# HTML 5 date field with different format text

Tags: html, date

Is there a way to force the HTML 5 date field to display other than the default text (placeholder text)
This html 5 field
`<input type="date" name="datetest" />`
display the control in browser like

[image]

can we change it to display like "mm/dd/yyy" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/3085279

Comment: Maybe you can look at this : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment options, there is a library, for masks input,if you are ready to use bootstrap, see the link: [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
 $('input.date-picker').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    });
```

Or if you prefer to use jquery only : [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

```
$('input.date-picker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
```